# A complex matrix $A$ such that. $A^3 = A^2 \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $4×4$ matrix over $C$ s.t. $Rank(A)=2$ and $A^3=A^2\neq0$. If $A$ is not diagonalizable then how to prove that:

There exists a vector $v$ s.t. $Av\neq 0$ and $A^2v=0$.

I know it is to be proved that $Imsp(A)$ is contained in $Nullsp(A)$, but really got no clue how to approach.

**My work:**
$x^2(x-1)$ is  the annihilating polynomial for $A$, but I am stuck in finding the characteristic polynomial. The only two possibilities are $x^3(x-1)$ and $x^2(x-1)^2$, but how to reject the later one?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: What things do you know?  Have you covered any of the following topics: Jordan Normal Form, the critereon for diagoanlizability in terms of the minimal polynomial, the structure theorem for f.g. modules over a PID?  With a bit of "technology" we can say a lot about what $A$ might be up to conjugation.  However, I assume that you want a concrete approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use jordon canonical form to prove this..

Since $A^2(A-I)=0$, only possible eigen values are $0,1$. Since $dim KerA=2$ , there wil be exactly two blocks corresponding to $0$ of size $(1,1)$ or $(2,1)$.

First case:

if  the blocksize  corresponding to $0$ is  (1,1) ,then because $A$ is not diagonalizable $A$ must be of this form

\begin{bmatrix}
0  &0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0& 1& 1\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}

second case:

if  the blocksize  corresponding to $0$ is  (2,1) ,then because $A$ is not diagonalizable $A$ must be of this form
\begin{bmatrix}
0  &1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0&0& 0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
 Since $A^2=A^3$ only second case is possible. In that case $e_2$ is the vector such that $Ae_2\neq0$ but $A^2e_2=0$

Comment: Black-horse I think first case may be rejected also by considering the power of $A$ in $A^2(A-I)$.

Comment: yes you are correct..@mathlover

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $Au\ne u$ then $A^2(Au-u)=0$.

> We don't need the info about the size (given as $4\times 4$) and rank (given as $2$) of the matrix at all; we do not even need that the matrix is over an algebraically closed field (given as  $\Bbb C$). If $A^2=A$ then $A$ is a projection and can be diagonalized, which is excluded. Hence There exists $u$ with $A^2u\ne Au$. For such $u$ let $v= Au-u$. Then $ Av = A^2u-Au\ne 0$ and $ A^2v=A^3u-A^2u=A^2u-A^2u=0$ as desired.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen thanks but will u kindly elaborate more..

Comment: @mathlover Writing $A$ in its Jordan Canonical Form explicitly, one of the two blocks corresponding to $0$ must have dimension $>1$ (this can be seen by using $A^2=A^3 \neq 0$), so there exists $u \neq 0$, such that $Au=u' \neq0$ & $Au'=0$, so $Au \neq u$, hence let $x= Au-u$, $Ax=u'\neq 0$ but $A^2 x =0$

Comment: @CYC Argumentation involving Jordan blocks or algebraically closed fields or dimensions or ranks are not needed

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen thanks a lot.great work.