# If $A^3=A^2$ then $A^2$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $A\in \mathbb{k}^{n\times n} $.

Prove that if $A^3=A^2$ then $A^2$ is diagonalizable.
Could you give me any hints on how to prove it?. I can't use the minimal polynomial, since we haven't seen it in class.
Thanks.

Comment: Hint; $A^3=A^2$ implies that $A^2(A-I)=0$, if $Av=v$ then $A^2v=v$ as well, and $\dim N(A-I)+\dim (A-I)(k^n)=n$, where $N$ denotes the nullspace and $(A-I)(k^n)$ denotes the image.

Comment: What if $A=\left[\matrix{0&1\cr 0&0\cr}\right]$? $A^3=A^2=0$, but $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @dfsfljn why does $A^2 v=v$ ? That would mean $v$ is an eigenvector for both $A$ and $A^2$ with the same eigenvalue right?

Comment: @CarlHeckman: the question is about $A^2$ being diagonalizable.

Comment: Just to nitpick, I think you mean $A^3=A^2\not=0$? Otherwise $A=0$ is a counterexample. - Also see answers of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525431/a-complex-matrix-a-such-that-a3-a2-neq-0/1525507)

Comment: @Eric_S. Sorry to say, but the zero matrix is a [diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix), so $A = 0$ is not a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A^2=B$, then $B^2 =B$. (In other words, $B^2$ is a projection.) Now, if $y=B(x)\in\mathop{\mathrm{im}} B$, then
$$y = B(x) = B(B(x)) = B(y).$$
So $y$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ of $B$. Also, if $y\in \ker B$, then $y$ is an eigenvalue corersponding to value $0$.

On the other hand, let $x\in k^{n\times n}$, we have
$$B(x) = B(B(x)).\tag{1}$$
so $x- B(x)\in \ker(B)$. Thus, 
$$k^{n\times n} = \mathop{\mathrm{im}} B+\ker B.$$
Lastly, if $x \in \ker B \cap \mathop{\mathrm{im}} B$, then
$$x=B(x) = B(B(x)) = 0.$$
So
$$k^{n\times n} = \mathop{\mathrm{im}} B \oplus \ker B.$$
Therefore, $B$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Thanks!, for some reason I didn't notice B was idempotent.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $A^4 = A^3 = A^2$, so the matrix $B = A^2$ satisfies $(B-I)B = B^2 - B = 0$. By Jordan Normal Form, since it satisfies a polynomial with no repeated roots, we must have $B$ is diagonalizable.

To proceed without heavy machinery:
Any matrix satisfying $B^2 = B$ is called an idempotent matrix. One can show

-$B$ must only have eigenvalues $0$ and $1$

-The eigenspace for $0$ corresponds to the null space by definition

-The eigenspace for $1$ corresponds to the column space by idempotency

Then by rank nullity, the dimension of the null space and the column space add to the dimension of your vector space, so your matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Is there a way to prove it without using the Jordan Normal Form? I haven't seen it in class either.

Comment: Edited to include an outline of proof without appealing to minimal polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Jordan form, we see we have Jordan blocks of size at most $2$, hence by decomposing you know any $0$-eigenvalue blocks of size $2$ square to all $0$ blocks, and any $1$ blocks have size at most $1$, and so remain unchanged.