# A $4 \times 4$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ such that rank$(A)=2$ and $A^3 =A^2 \neq 0$ and $A$ is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

This question was asked in my linear algebra quiz and I am having Difficulty in it . SO, I am asking for help here.

Edit : I am looking for an answer which solves it without using Jordan Forms. I have seen some Duplicate which use Jordan forms and which don't answer my 1 part. So, I asked it.

> Let $A$  be  a $4 \times 4$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ such that rank (A)=2 and $A^3 =A^2 \neq 0$ and $A$ is not diagonalizable. (1) Then what is characteristic polynomial of $A$? (2) does there exists a vector v such that $Av\neq 0$ but $A^2 v=0$?

I have proved that minimal polynomial = $x^2 (x-1)$ but unable to deduce characteristic polynomial and (2) also.

> Edit :For minimal polynomial I used that $A$ is not diagonalizable and $A^2 \neq 0$. So , (x) (x-1)( Diagonalizability) , x , $x^2$ can't be minimal polynomial. Also , rank =2 implies $x-1$ can't be .

Hope it's fine now.

Can you please help?

Comment: How did you prove that the minimal polynomial is $x^2 (x-1)$? Why can't it be $x (x-1)$?

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at that minimal polynomial? (Click "edit" beneath your question to do so.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A complex matrix $A$ such that. $A^3 = A^2 \neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525431/a-complex-matrix-a-such-that-a3-a2-neq-0)

Comment: @daw I have seen these similar questions but I am looking for an answer without use of Jordan forms.

Comment: @lhf Kindly see edit!

Comment: @JohnHughes Kindly see edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the minimal polynomial $m(x) = x^2(x-1)$ must divide the characteristic polynomial, and any zeros of the characteristic polynomial must also be zeros of the minimal polynomial. Since $A$ has size $4$, the characteristic polynomial must have degree $4$.

Thus, there are two possible characteristic polynomials: either we have $p(x) = x^2(x-1)^2$ or $p(x) = x^3(x-1)$. In order to eliminate the first possibility, we need to use the fact that $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 2$.

Suppose for contradiction that $x^2(x-1)^2$ is the characteristic polynomial. Because the exponent of $x$ is $2$, we note that $\dim \ker A^2 \leq 2 = \dim \ker A$. Since it always holds that $\ker A \subseteq \ker A^2$, we have $\ker A = \ker A^2$. However, the fact that $A^2(A-I) = 0$ implies that the image of $A - I$ is a subset of the kernel of $A^2$. Thus, the image of $A - I$ is a subset of the kernel of $A$, which means that $A(A-I) = 0$. This implies that the minimal polynomial is $m(x) = x(x-1)$, which means that $A$ is diagonalizable, contradicting the given information.

As we see in the above proof, it must hold that $\dim \ker A \subsetneq \dim \ker A^2$. This means that there exists a vector $v \in \ker A^2 \setminus \ker A$, which is to say that $Av \neq 0$ but $A^2 v = 0$.

Comment: How did you wrote in third para line 2 Dim $ker A^2 \leq 2$?

Comment: @User It comes down to either a definition of or a statement about algebraic multiplicity. What is your definition of algebraic multiplicity?

Comment: Number of times an eigenvalues is repeated in Characterstic polynomial , I use that defination

Comment: @User If that's the case, have you already established that every linear transformation can be upper-triangularized?

Comment: Ya  I have learnt that result

Comment: Ok. So, without loss of generality, suppose that $A$ is upper triangular. With the characteristic polynomial equal to $x^2(x-1)^2$, we have
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&*&*&*\\0&1&*&*\\0&0&0&*\\0&0&0&0}.
$$
We see that
$$
A^2 = \pmatrix{1^2&*&*&*\\0&1^2&*&*\\0&0&0^2&*\\0&0&0&0^2} = 
\pmatrix{1&*&*&*\\0&1&*&*\\0&0&0&*\\0&0&0&0},
$$
which is to say that $A^2$ is upper triangular of the same form. Because the first two columns are linearly independent, $A^2$ has rank at least $2$ and therefore kernel of dimension at most $2$.

Comment: Thanks! got it.

Comment: @User I pressed enter early before; see my edit

Comment: @User You're welcome!